# Inferred rules in makefile

Tags: makefile

I'd like to know what's wrong with my makefile where I'm using inferred rules:

```
nvcc=/usr/local/cuda-6.5/bin/nvcc
opts="-O3 -arch=sm_35 -rdc=true -lcudadevrt -Xcompiler -fopenmp -lpng"

base: ignore dynamic predict

%: ./../source/%.cu
    $(nvcc) $> $(opts) -o $@
```

The error I get:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `ignore.exe', needed by `base'.  Stop.
```

Of course there's no such a rule, but shouldn't `make` assume that `ignore` is hidden in `%`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your error message doesn't match your makefile (nowhere in your makefile is the target `ignore.exe` mentioned).  This makes me cautious that there maybe other relevant differences between what you're running and what you've shown us.

In any event, a rule like `%: ./../source/%.cu` will match a target if and only if there's a prerequisite that matches the pattern as well.  So if your target is `ignore.exe` and the target pattern is `%` that means that the `%` in the prerequisite will expand to `ignore.exe` as well.  So make will look for a prerequisite `./../source/ignore.exe.cu`.  If that file exists (or can be made itself) then make will try to build the target.  If it doesn't exist and can't be created, then make will ignore that rule and keep looking for more rules that might match the target and where the prerequisite exists or can be built.

If none are found, then you get the error you see (*No rule to make target*)

Comment: The only difference between what was run and what was shown is in the `.exe` extension.

Comment: Yeah, actually my file was named `mandelbrot-ignore.cu` instead of `ignore.cu`.